# my GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3, javabuilders

In my GlassFish Server, I got this error message:

```
In-place deployment at D:\simpers\simpers\simpers-war\build\web<br>
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false<br>
D:\simpers\simpers\simpers-war\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1118: The module has not been deployed.<br>
See the server log for details.<br>
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)<br>
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem. Check you log and verify if it throws a missing Jar exception, that was my problem. For example, this was the log file

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/undercouch/bson4jackson/BsonFactory
```

Then, just add the missing Jar files.

You can find your server log file at:

```
Your_GlassFish_Location\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log
```

Hope it helps you! CYA

Answer (score 2):

I guess your jar file is broken or missing.

Solution: 
For Netbeans IDE
go to project, select Project Properties.

From Project Properties wizard, Select Libraries.

select compile (tab), see any red line indicating Broken reference or missing library.

If you find any thing, remove it.

Add the corresponding library/JAR to the project.